# check internet connectivity in tizen

Tags: sockets, tizen

I am trying to find out what is the best way check internet connectivity in tizen. Although there is a connection manager I can think of a scenerio where it would not work. Suppose the device is connected to wifi but wifi is not connected to internet. What is the best best way to resolve this issue? I am thinking of using `getaddrinfo`? But would not that resolve to `IP` using `cached` value. Then should I connect to a known website (e.g. google although some country might block it)?

Comment: As you mentioned, In case of wifi is not worked, How can I check it?  I think  it is only way to check real site connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can hit an address and check for response for certain time of interval. If there is no response for say 2 min or so then you can show message to user that there is some problem with Internet connection.